# How to do an edit to firebase using onlongpress on listtile

Tags: flutter, dart, crud

im trying to make an simple crud usuing firebase, but i cant make the edit, i tried to do an modalEdit to create an form to edit, but i cant get the context, then trying to put the showDialog inside the onLongPress and didnt work too, can i get any tip in how to do it, or help to fix my modalEdit, this is all my code, did it all on the homepage.dart

````
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  static String tag = '/home';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Firebase.initializeApp();
    var snapshots = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('todo')
        .where('excluido', isEqualTo: false)
        .snapshots();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('CRUD firebase'),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.pink[100],
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: snapshots,
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
            }
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
                var doc = snapshot.data.docs[i];
                var item = doc.data();

                return Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                  ),
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 12, 10, 0),
                  child: ListTile(
                    leading: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        item['feito']
                            ? Icons.check_circle
                            : Icons.radio_button_unchecked,
                        size: 30,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () => doc.reference.update({
                        'feito': !item['feito'],
                      }),
                    ),
                    title: Text(item['titulo']),
                    subtitle: Text(item['descricao']),
                    onLongPress: () => modalEdit(context),
                    trailing: IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.delete, size: 30),
                      onPressed: () => doc.reference.update({
                        'excluido': true,
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () => modalCreate(context),
        tooltip: 'Adicionar novo',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }

  modalCreate(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<FormState> form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    var titulo = TextEditingController();
    var descricao = TextEditingController();

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Criar nova tarefa'),
            content: Form(
              key: form,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Titulo'),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Ex: ir no mercado',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                        controller: titulo,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Este campo nao pode ser vazio';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text('Descricao'),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Ex: comprar pao',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                        controller: descricao,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Este campo nao pode ser vazio';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (form.currentState.validate()) {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').add(
                      {
                        'titulo': titulo.text,
                        'descricao': descricao.text,
                        'feito': false,
                        'excluido': false,
                      },
                    );
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Confirmar'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Text('Cancelar'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  modalEdit(BuildContext context) {
    GlobalKey<FormState> form = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    var titulo = TextEditingController();
    var descricao = TextEditingController();

    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Editar tarefa'),
            content: Form(
              key: form,
              child: Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 3,
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Novo Titulo'),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Ex: ir no mercado',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                        controller: titulo,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Este campo nao pode ser vazio';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                    SizedBox(height: 20),
                    Text('Nova Descricao'),
                    TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            hintText: 'Ex: comprar pao',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5))),
                        controller: descricao,
                        validator: (value) {
                          if (value.isEmpty) {
                            return 'Este campo nao pode ser vazio';
                          }
                          return null;
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  if (form.currentState.validate()) {
                    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('todo').add(
                      {
                        'titulo': titulo.text,
                        'descricao': descricao.text,
                        'feito': false,
                        'excluido': false,
                      },
                    );
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  }
                },
                child: Text('Confirmar'),
              ),
              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
                child: Text('Cancelar'),
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
  }
}```
````

Comment: I think dialog use overlay context Please try context as "context.navigationKey().currentState.overlay.context" Might works